# fmt.Scanf is not waiting for console input

Tags: go, scanf

scanf is not waiting for input. Other issue raised have : \n left in stdin because they have pressed ENTER before scanf. In my case first thing I doing is running scanf -> no \n leftover in my case. I am new to golang but as per my C concept I am doing nothing wrong.

also tried fmt.Scanf("%d\n",&n)  <--- but it does not make sense as there are no \n leftover for this scan.

```
func main() {
    var a int = 0
    var b int = 1
    var c int
    var n int 
    fmt.Scanf("%d\n",&n)
    //fmt.Printf("%d \n",n)
    var i int
    fmt.Printf("%d %d ", a, b)
    for i = 0; i < n-2; i++ {
        c = (a + b) % 10
        fmt.Printf("%d ", c)
        a = b
        b = c
    }
}
```

below is my code link in playground
https://play.golang.org/p/_OWtakKsDHn

I am getting result : 
0 1 
Program exited.

Comment: Did you try this on the playground only, or locally? It should run locally. I don't think the playground supports console input.

Comment: Please include the code within your post. Not in some links.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly the go playground does not support console input.
It was even mentioned on the GitHub issue [here](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16667#issuecomment-410038280) that they are not planning on bringing this as a feature.

Also if you look at [this](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/16667#issuecomment-239103042) comment stating a possible solution to your problem which allows you to read from os.Stdin on the playground if you assign it to a file.